# Is the css setting speak:none now equivalent to aria-hidden="true"?

Tags: html, css, wai-aria, accessibility, css-speech

I'm just wondering whether I should expect browsers and assistive technilogy circa January 2015 to use speak:none in a manner equivalent to setting aria-hidden="true". I'd like to indicate that some semi-opaque text should be ignored, and am wondering whether I can do it in one operation (just adding a class that sets the opaque style and speak:none, rather than adding the class and setting the aria-hidden attribute).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the scenario; is the text here obscured by some modal UI (eg lightbox); or is this just text that is visually hidden by setting opacity to fully transparent instead of (for whatever reason) using `display:none` or `visibility:hidden`, which are the usual ways to hide content?

Comment: @BrendanMcK, the scenario here is that the text is greyed out in a way that makes it visually irrelevant. I would like it to be irrelevant to accessibility devices as well.

Comment: If it's really "visually irrelevant", then aria-hidden sounds like a good match. Hard to know for sure without seeing the UI perhaps; as a counter-example, disabled buttons are typically greyed-out, but still visible and still available to screenreaders, since they're still relevant, just not actionable at that specific point in time (eg because not all fields n a form have yet been filled in).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There does not seem to be reliable data on support to `speak`, but it seems to be unimplemented.

Independently of the implementation status, `speak: none` is *not* equivalent to `aria-hidden="true"`.

According to the CSS Speech Module CR, the [`speak`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-speech/#speaking-props-speak) property “determines whether or not to render text aurally”, i.e. audibly.

According to the ARIA specification, [`aria-hidden`](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties#aria-hidden) “indicates that the *element* and all of its descendants are not visible or *perceivable* to *any* user as implemented by the author” (italic in the original).

Thus, `aria-hidden="true"` does not *cause* anything; it just *declares* that the author has hidden the element. And it relates to all kinds of rendering: audible, visible, tactile, or whatever modalities might be invented in the future.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the difference in meaning between the two methods and for the quote from the ARIA specification. Now I have to wonder wherever aria-hidden="true" is appropriate for text that has been rendered semantically irrelevant through opaqueness, yet is still somewhat visible. Ideally, the text would just be completely hidden, but in this case I don't have control of the design, only the implementation.

Comment: @MikeGodin, if it is semantically irrelevant (i.e. meaningless), I think it should have `role=presentation` set on it.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela - `role=presentation` does not mean that the text content is irrelevant/meaningless; it only means that the _semantics of the tag itself_ are to be ignored: so, for example, `<button role="presentation">OK</button>` would be treated as plain text `OK` or as `<span>OK</span>`, and not as a button.

Comment: @BrendanMcK, I stand corrected. I’m afraid I can’t say what should be done with textual content that is meant to be purely decorative and therefore ignored in non-visual rendering. Perhaps the best one can do is to set `display: none` media-dependently, for any non-visual media.

Comment: `aria-hidden="true"` is actually perfect for hiding content outright from screenreaders; though have to be careful to use it appropriately - [see caveats in the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties#aria-hidden). If, for some other reason, text was made invisible to sighted users by setting opacity to transparent instead of the usual techniques of using display:none/visibility:hidden, then setting `aria-hidden="true"` would also ensure screenreaders ignored it. aria-hidden is also very useful for hiding the "grayed out" contend behind modal dialogs/lightboxes.

Comment: Be aware that `aria-hidden="true"` doesn't stop keyboards from being able to focus on elements so slapping `aria-hidden="true"` onto something doesn't automatically get you over the accessibility line when you set a menu or something to opacity: 0. You also need to set _all interactive elements_ inside the hidden element to tabindex="-1".

Answer (score 2):

**Use this combination:**

- speak: never;
- speak-as: spell-out;

**Values for speak**

- auto: As long as the element is not display: block and is
  visibility:visible, text will be read aurally.
- never: text will not be read aurally
- always: text will be read aurally, regardless of display    value or
  ancestor values of speak.

**Values for speak-as**
Related to speak as it gets into how the text will be read:

- normal: Takes the browser’s default speak settings.
- spell-out: Instructs the browser to spell a properties content
  instead of speaking out full words.
- digits: Reads numbers one at a time, like 69 would be read “six
  nine”. Nice.
- literal-punctuation: Spells out punctations (like semicolons) rather
  than treating them like pauses.
- no-punctuation: Entirely skips punctuation.

Answer (score -1):

To answer the *intent* of my original question -- I was wondering if I could add a class that sets the opaque style and disables the text from screen readers, rather than add the class **and also** set the aria-hidden attribute.

What I ended up doing was to set **only** the aria-hidden attribute, then in my css use [aria-hidden] instead of a class name to set the opaque style.

```css
p[aria-hidden="true"] {
  opacity: 0.3;
  pointer-events: none;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<p aria-hidden="true">Ignore this text!</p>
<p>See this text!</p>
```