# Hide pseudo elements from screen readers using aria-hidden?

Tags: html, css, unicode, pseudo-element

I have a site where a lot of the links are appended using an `:after` psuedo-element with the unicode character `\2192` (a right pointing arrow: →).

Since pseudo elements cannot be manipulated with JS, nor can I apply the attribute `aria-hidden="true"` via CSS, how can I hide these elements from a screen reader?

I can't really change the markup since I need the arrows to be dynamically added whenever a user ads content in the CMS that includes a link.

Here's how it's implemented:

```
p a:after {
    content: ' \2192';
}
```

Comment: Pseudoelement can be manipulated with js, it's just harder. Please add simple code snippet, it will be easier to answer your question.

Comment: @PStarczewski I added sample code to my original post. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Know this is old, but recently had to answer this too and [eventually found a better answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47451397/2144578)

pseudo-elements; alternative text can be indicated after a /:

```
.expandable::before {
  content: "\2193" / ""; 
}
```

In this case the blank alt text will cause this content to be ignored.

[Admittedly support isn’t great at the moment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content#Browser_compatibility) (just Chromium based browsers) but hopefully that’ll improve. Until then you should add a fallback without the Alt text or browsers like Safari ignore the whole line:

```
.expandable::before {
  content: "\2193"; 
  content: "\2193" / ""; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I still don't fully understand your problem as code is kinda short, but here is a possible solution. You can create a class "arrow" and toggle it(either onclick or however you want) so that your pseudoelement can be add or remove like any other.

```js
function myFunction(el) {
    el.classList.toggle("arrow");
}
```

```css
.arrow:after{
  content: ' \2192';
}
```

```html
<div>
<p><a class="arrow" href="#" onclick="myFunction(this)">CONTENT</a></p>
</div>
```

if it's not what you're looking for, let me know, I'll come up with other solution after further explanation about your problem.

Comment: Thanks that's helpful. The only thing is the arrow is added to so many elements, so I can't really control it via a class. My css is has about 10 or so elements where the pseudo-element is tacked on (for example .event.press h3 a:after or .text.two-col a:after). There is no single class that controls it.

Comment: I've edited snippet, you can use "this" as function argument, so that you don't have to use class to select element. Simply when element is triggered(not necessarily with onclick) it will pass reference to itself.

Comment: I should clarify, I only need to hide the element for screen readers using the attribute "aria-hidden". None of the arrows are setup with classes, instead I'm adding them through the parent class. For example, I might add arrows to all of the links in the div #homepage, or add arrows to all .button. There is no one class to catch all of these pseudo elements.

Comment: Oh, I've finally understood your problem. I don't think it's possible to aquire that, as it will cover the whole segment, not only the :after part. Only semi-solution for you I can come up with is to try speak: none; property. It's different from aria-hidden, but may work. Here is similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27751738/is-the-css-setting-speaknone-now-equivalent-to-aria-hidden-true